# WPF Two Datagrids One Selected Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two DataGrids and only want to have a selected row in one of the DataGrids at a time. when i make a selection in one DataGrid, the selected row in the other DataGrid should be removed. I have tried using the OnSelectionChanged even to change the selection in the opposing DataGrid, but this in turn caused the OnSelectionChanged even in the current DataGrid to be called, and i end up with no selection at all. Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataGrid1CollectionView}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DataGrid1SelectedArisingGroup}"
          SelectionChanged="DataGrid1SelectionChanged"
>
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid2"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataGrid2CollectionView}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DataGrid2SelectedArisingGroup}"
          SelectionChanged="DataGrid2SelectionChanged"
>
</DataGrid>

private void DataGrid1SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid2.SelectedItem=null;
        }

private void DataGrid2SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid1.SelectedItem=null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unsubscribe/detach the SelectionChanged event of the second datagrid while a selection is done in the first datagrid & vice versa & then reattach after executing your logic - in this case unselecting the item.

I have written a code sample below for one of the datagrid's selection changed event. Extending it for the 2nd datagrid is pretty straight forward.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:name="dgr1" SelectionChanged="dgr1_Selection"/>
<DataGrid x:name="dgr2" SelectionChanged="dgr2_Selection"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void dgr1_Selection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dgr2.SelectionChanged -= dgr2_Selection;
    //unselecte the selected item of dgr2 - Set the IsSelected property of 
    //the Selected item to false or dgr2.SelectedItem=null
    dgr2.SelectionChanged += dgr2_Selection;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thankyou. dont know why i didnt think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean which it save event.

```
bool bSave = false;

public void OnSelectedChange_OneDatagrid(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(bSave)
    {
        // You can make the treatment
    }
    else
    {
        bSave = false;
    }
}
public void OnSelectedChange_TwoDatagrid(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(!bSave)
    {
        // You can make the treatment
    }
    else
    {
        bSave = true;
    }
}
```

I make this when I am in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do it is to bind SelectedItem in TwoWay mode of each DataGrid to separate property and set SelectedItem1/SelectedItem2 to null, also you can set 3rd property from their setters, if you need to use selected item somewhere else (to bind OverviewView data for example).

Properties in your ViewModel:

```
private SomeType _selectedItem;
public SomeType SelectedItem
{
    get => _selectedItem;
    private set
    {
        if (!SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value)) return;
    }
}

private SomeType _selectedItem2;
public SomeType SelectedItem2
{
    get => _selectedItem2;
    set
    {
        if (!SetProperty(ref _selectedItem2, value) || value is null) return;
        SelectedItem = _selectedItem2;
        SelectedItem1 = null;
    }
}

private SomeType _selectedItem1;
public SomeType SelectedItem1
{
    get => _selectedWaitItem;
    set
    {
        if (!SetProperty(ref _selectedItem1, value) || value is null) return;
        SelectedItem = _selectedItem1;
        SelectedItem2 = null;
    }
}
```

DataGrid' SelectedItem xaml:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

P.S. SetProperty() method is from CommunityToolkit.Mvvm which handles OnPropertyChanged event